# Why am I using two ".by" in order for my code to work? Also, why can't I find an element based on ID?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to test logging into my bank provider and for some reason it only sends text into username textbox only when I have

`"by.Byname..." instead of just "by.name, user-id"` 
The element that I'm trying to enter text into only populates once user selects "Login" first, not sure if it has anything to do with that

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common import by
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager



options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()),
                          options=options)

driver.get("https://www.53.com/")
driver.maximize_window()

driver.find_element(by.By.NAME, "user-id").clear()
driver.find_element(by.By.NAME, "user-id").send_keys("username")`
```

Originally I tried:
`driver.find_element(by.NAME, "user-id").clear()` 
But, I was prompted with:

```
driver.find_element(by.NAME, "user-id").clear()
                       ^^
NameError: name 'By' is not defined. Did you mean: 'by'?`
```

Comment: Every Selenium example on the internet I have ever seen uses this import `from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By` -- so why are you using a different import?  Why are you trying to use `by` on its own?

Comment: I have no idea, just copying a tutorial, I'll try that

Answer (score -1):

The reason you are using by.BY in your code is because you imported the module not the BY class.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

if you are using 'Visual studio code' you can hold Ctrl and click by and it will open the .py file which will give you a better understanding of the file structure.

To find an element by 'id' you have to pass 'id' as  the first param to the find_element function.

```
d.find_element(By.ID, 'The id')
```

In your code you are searching by Name which would be something like 'password' or 'email'

and just for a bit of clarity all By is doing is returning a string, this is what it looks like.

```
class By:
    """Set of supported locator strategies."""

    ID = "id"
    XPATH = "xpath"
    LINK_TEXT = "link text"
    PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT = "partial link text"
    NAME = "name"
    TAG_NAME = "tag name"
    CLASS_NAME = "class name"
    CSS_SELECTOR = "css selector"
```